# Reset Formik fields from parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using **Formik** for form validation in React application. My Parent component (**Users**) - displays list of **users**. If we select any user, details of the user will be displayed in another component to the right side in a form. The child component (**UserDetails**) displays the details of the selected user. All the details are displayed in textboxes in child component, which we can change and update the details(Here I am using FORMIK to validate fields before updating).

I have a scenario where I am trying to clear all fields (reset form values of **UserDetails**) on clicking a button from parent component (**Users**). I am trying to change the initial values of the Formik Form from parent component. Some how its not working for me.

I want to clear all fields of a Formik Form from it's parent component.

Comment: You can change it's `key`

Comment: You can also use the [enableReinitialize](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean) prop and update the initialValues

Comment: I am already using  **enableReinitialize** option. But not working.